# sql querying the price-history for all the items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

```
Table 1  
Transact Item Status   
0         A      1  
1         A      1     
2         B      1  
3         C      0
```

...

```
Table 2  
Item     Item Name      
A          shoe1  
B          shoe2  
C          shoe3
```

...

```
Table 3  
Transact   Price  
0            23  
1            22  
2            10  
3            50
```

How do I get the transaction history for ALL the items? It is easy to get it for one particular item by entering the item or its name, but how about for ALL the items? Presumably, I wish to plot the transaction history for every item, for ALL the items?

Thanks!

Comment: which is it - mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide the expected output. Your sample data have only one single position, which creates 1:n-data  (Table 1 with two entries to item A)...

Comment: @Blorgbeard: mysql, sorry for lack of clarification.

Comment: @Shnugo: About the output, I will be doing some calculations with the transaction prices. I guess a table with those prices should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.ItemName , t3.Price
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2  ON t1.Item = t2.Item
INNER JOIN Table3 t3  ON t1.Transact = t3.Transact
```

Comment: Thanks, M.Ali! What if I add an extra column in Table1, which is the ItemType, but now I want to do the same (i.e., get the transaction history) per ItemType, for all the ItemType's ?

Comment: One ItemType can contain multiple items. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for repeating my comment; just learned how to direct you directly. So, what if I add an extra column in Table1, which is the ItemType, but now I want to do the same (i.e., get the transaction history) per ItemType, for all the ItemType's ? An ItemType can have multiple items. Thanks!